# What is the stand of "impossibly difficult" or "impossibly high"?

Tags: grammar

let's see a sentence

"The examination is impossibly difficult to get passed."

What exactly the sentence is trying to say?
dose it mean

"The exam is extremely hard" or

"The exam is so easy that it's impossible to think it is difficult.

this confuses me a lot, the word "impossibly" seems contradictory to the word "difficult"

Answer (score 1):

'Impossibly' is being used as an intensifier here. It means that the exam is very very difficult. The word is often used to denote near-impossibility. Some people might criticise the use of 'impossibly' for something that is not actually and literally 'impossible', but almost everyone uses it in everyday speech on occasions. However, you may not find it used in a serious piece of writing, unless something is actually and literally 'impossible'.